# MVC: Nearly all my content is generated in the model, should I use the view for miscellaneous content?

Tags: model-view-controller, codeigniter

I'm building a web app where 80-90% of the content is either a form or a table of data. I am utilizing MVC through codeiginiter.

I have built classes to deal with generating the forms and tables and these forms and tables are created in the model and the view is passed the Form/Table object which simply echos it. This means that my views are extremely lean and I reuse views because most of them simply do:-

```
* load head and header views *

<?=$form?>

* load footer view *
```

So I only need a new view when I have a different layout, i.e. 2 forms on a single page.

The question is when I have some content which isn't a form or a table, for example some summary information or simply a paragraph of text, where would be the most intutitve place to find it? I feel that putting it in the view will be misleading because all of the other content manipulation is done by my model, so if I want to edit a form or a table I look to the model and very rarely even look at my views.

I was thinking of maybe creating simple 'Content' class which would deal with outputting paragraph and summary info... Then I could create the content in the model...

Edit:

Thinking about this again, since summary information needs to be generated, this should naturally be done in the model. For 'fixed' content like a paragraph of text since it is still data, despite being static and not nessessary to store in the database it still has to be stored somewhere and makes sense to have it in the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would be more logic to have views that do the formatting work you are doing in the model.

Models should return this kind of data in form of arrays, and then you should have a view able to lay out a form out of an array. In Codeigniter this goes very nicely thanks to the form helper.

In example, a form creator that works with Bootstrap 2: https://github.com/FoOlRulez/FoOlFuuka/blob/master/application/views/admin/form_creator.php

The beauty of views is that you can stack and mix them, which can solve your problem. In example you can call them like this:

```
$data['form'] = $this->radix->board_structure(); // this holds a huge array that I associate to a database model
$this->viewdata["function_title"] = _('Editing board:') . ' ' . $board->shortname;
$this->viewdata["main_content_view"] = $this->load->view('admin/form_creator', $data, TRUE);
$this->load->view('admin/default', $this->viewdata);
```

In my application this sets a title to the page, it makes the form the content of the page and sticks it into the default admin panel wrapper. You can do basically anything as long as you have it into views.

Comment: My models aren't doing any formatting, they simply setup the form field names, types and validation rules and create a Form object. The formatting is encapsulated in my Form library.

I think I will stick with the object route for now - it allows me to abstract away the complexities of all of the extras that go along with forms, for instance I am able to have a modal ajax form simply by telling a table that it is editable: the Table object calls upon my model which throws back the correct Form object and puts it into the view with the required js.